# Does dplyr::if_else evaluate both TRUE and FALSE at the same time?

Tags: r, dplyr

Consider the following example:

```r
library(dplyr)

# sample data 
set.seed(1)
mydf <- data.frame(value = as.logical(sample(0:1, 15, replace = TRUE)), group = rep(letters[1:3],each = 5), index = 1:5)

# finds either index of first "TRUE" value by group, or the last value. 
# works with base::ifelse
mydf %>% group_by(group) %>% mutate(max_value = ifelse(all(!value), max(index), index[min(which(value))]))
#> # A tibble: 15 x 4
#> # Groups:   group [3]
#>    value group index   max_value
#>    <lgl> <fct> <int>      <int>
#>  1 FALSE a         1          2
#>  2 TRUE  a         2          2
#>  3 FALSE a         3          2
#>  4 FALSE a         4          2
#>  5 TRUE  a         5          2
#>  6 FALSE b         1          4
#>  7 FALSE b         2          4
#>  8 FALSE b         3          4
#>  9 TRUE  b         4          4
#> 10 TRUE  b         5          4
#> 11 FALSE c         1          5
#> 12 FALSE c         2          5
#> 13 FALSE c         3          5
#> 14 FALSE c         4          5
#> 15 FALSE c         5          5

# the same gives a warning with dplyr::if_else
mydf %>% group_by(group) %>% mutate(max_value = if_else(all(!value), max(index), index[min(which(value))]))

#> Warning in min(which(value)): no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf

#> # A tibble: 15 x 4
#> # Groups:   group [3]
#>    value group index  max_value
#>    <lgl> <fct> <int>      <int>
#>  1 FALSE a         1          2
#>  2 TRUE  a         2          2
#>  3 FALSE a         3          2
#>  4 FALSE a         4          2
#>  5 TRUE  a         5          2
#>  6 FALSE b         1          4
#>  7 FALSE b         2          4
#>  8 FALSE b         3          4
#>  9 TRUE  b         4          4
#> 10 TRUE  b         5          4
#> 11 FALSE c         1          5
#> 12 FALSE c         2          5
#> 13 FALSE c         3          5
#> 14 FALSE c         4          5
#> 15 FALSE c         5          5
```

As commented in the code - `dplyr::if_else` does result in the warning

> Warning in min(which(value)): no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf

Removing the "all FALSE" group c - no warning any more:

```
mydf_allTRUE <- mydf
mydf_allTRUE[14, 'value'] <- TRUE

mydf_allTRUE %>% group_by(group) %>% mutate(max_value = if_else(all(!value), max(index), index[min(which(value))]))
#> # A tibble: 15 x 4
#> # Groups:   group [3]
#>    value group index max_value
#>    <lgl> <fct> <int>     <int>
#>  1 FALSE a         1         2
#>  2 TRUE  a         2         2
#>  3 FALSE a         3         2
#>  4 FALSE a         4         2
#>  5 TRUE  a         5         2
#>  6 FALSE b         1         4
#>  7 FALSE b         2         4
#>  8 FALSE b         3         4
#>  9 TRUE  b         4         4
#> 10 TRUE  b         5         4
#> 11 FALSE c         1         4
#> 12 FALSE c         2         4
#> 13 FALSE c         3         4
#> 14 TRUE  c         4         4
#> 15 FALSE c         5         4
```

<sup>Created on 2019-12-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

What confuses me, is that (*I believe that*) I constructed the `TRUE` part in a way that the `FALSE` part (`index[min(which(value))]`) **must** contain a value. Why does this then give a warning? 
It is problematic, because I have data with several thousand groups and most of them are in the "FALSE" bit and the warnings make the computation extremely slow.

I am happy to use `base::ifelse`, but I just wondered how `dplyr::if_else` is evaluating both TRUE and FALSE sides, is this somehow at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because we are checking cases where there are groups that return `NULL with`which(value)`

```
min(NULL)
#[1] Inf
```

> Warning message: In min(NULL) : no non-missing arguments to min;
>   returning Inf

---

An option is to subject the `which` output by indexing with `[1]` to return `NA`

```
mydf %>%
   group_by(group) %>%
   mutate(max_value = if_else(all(!value), max(index), index[which(value)[1]]))
# A tibble: 15 x 4
# Groups:   group [3]
#   value group index max_value
#   <lgl> <fct> <int>     <int>
# 1 FALSE a         1         2
# 2 TRUE  a         2         2
# 3 FALSE a         3         2
# 4 FALSE a         4         2
# 5 TRUE  a         5         2
# 6 FALSE b         1         4
# 7 FALSE b         2         4
# 8 FALSE b         3         4
# 9 TRUE  b         4         4
#10 TRUE  b         5         4
#11 FALSE c         1         5
#12 FALSE c         2         5
#13 FALSE c         3         5
#14 FALSE c         4         5
#15 FALSE c         5         5
```

---

Also, in this case, as we are returning a single element, `if/else` would be more appropriate

```
mydf %>%
    group_by(group) %>%
    mutate(max_value = if(all(!value)) max(index) else index[which(value)[1]])
# A tibble: 15 x 4
# Groups:   group [3]
#   value group index max_value
#   <lgl> <fct> <int>     <int>
# 1 FALSE a         1         2
# 2 TRUE  a         2         2
# 3 FALSE a         3         2
# 4 FALSE a         4         2
# 5 TRUE  a         5         2
# 6 FALSE b         1         4
# 7 FALSE b         2         4
# 8 FALSE b         3         4
# 9 TRUE  b         4         4
#10 TRUE  b         5         4
#11 FALSE c         1         5
#12 FALSE c         2         5
#13 FALSE c         3         5
#14 FALSE c         4         5
#15 FALSE c         5         5
```

Comment: so, you are saying that `dplyr::if_else` indeed seems to test both TRUE and FALSE at the same time?

Comment: Thanks for the indexing idea, that's very clever

Comment: @Tjebo `if_else` comes with additional checks like types etc.  In your case, there is no need for `ifelse/if_else` as it is returning a single output

Comment: This is indeed very true. It actually is very revealing to me, as I had until now not quite grasped this essential difference between ifelse/ if_else and if/else. Makes a lot of sense. Thanks