# Weird recognition of NA in if_else vs ifelse

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr

I have a tibble with a column defined as double. When I try to summarize that column by groups, in which some of them there is only NA, something weird happens. I can recreate it like this (I do it with `double` because that's what I used in my real code):

```
tibble(x = c(1, NA, NA)) %>% 
  filter(row_number()>1) %>% 
  summarize(x = if_else(!all(is.na(x)), max(x, na.rm = T), NA_real_))
# A tibble: 1 × 1
      x
  <dbl>
1    NA
Warning message:
There was 1 warning in `summarize()`.
ℹ In argument: `x = if_else(!all(is.na(x)), max(x, na.rm = T), NA_real_)`.
Caused by warning in `max()`:
! no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
```

So, the part being summarized only has `NA`s, in which case `max()` removes them, and then tries to find maximum from the empty vector, leading to the warning and `-Inf`. But the `if_else()` should take care of it: if all are `NA`, don't go to `max()` at all. (I found this suggestion earlier somewhere in Stackoverflow, but can't find it anymore.) And the `-Inf` even isn't in the output. So apparently the output is correct, but the warning still bothers me.

The similar condition works if I do it with `ifelse()`:

```
tibble(x = c(1, NA, NA)) %>% 
   filter(row_number()>1) %>% 
   summarize(x = ifelse(!all(is.na(x)), max(x, na.rm = T), NA_real_))
# A tibble: 1 × 1
  x
<dbl>
1    NA
```

No warning.

What is `ifelse()` doing differently from `if_else()` here?

Comment: `if_else()` calculates both sides (so does `ifelse()` but it doesn't show warnings): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66291511/prevent-undesired-warning-resulting-from-calculation-of-both-yes-and-no-in-dplyr

Comment: This would be the simplest answer, but it seems to me that @konrad-rudolph below disagrees? Also, what would be the point of making if_else if it's essentially the same function?

Comment: What @konrad_rudolph is saying is that you use `if_else()`/`ifelse()`if you need to test a condition for **each element** in a vector so for instance if you want to test if each element in `x` is `NA`. In your case you're testing the **entire vector** and you only get one logical value from the result which is why just a normal `if` is enough.

Answer (score 3):

The reason is that `if_else(condition, true, false)` always evaluates both arguments (`true` and `false`), regardless of the value of `condition`.

By contrast, `ifelse(test, yes, no)` has a special case when none of the `test` conditions are true (or false), in which case it doesn’t evaluate its `yes` (or `no`) argument:

```
…
if (length(ypos) > 0L)
    ans[ypos] <- rep(yes, length.out = len)[ypos]
if (length(npos) > 0L)
    ans[npos] <- rep(no, length.out = len)[npos]
…
```

`if_else()` does not do this since it isn’t terribly useful: both `ifelse()` and `if_else()` are *vectorised*, after all, and the expectation is that the first argument has length > 1.

In fact, idiomatically your code wouldn’t be written using either of these functions, but rather `if…else`, because there is only a single condition so the entire reason for using these functions (= vectorisation) does not apply:

```
tibble(x = c(1, NA, NA)) %>% 
  filter(row_number() > 1) %>% 
  summarize(x = if (all(is.na(x))) NA_real_ else max(x, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Comment: I don't get your last paragraph. I thought case_when is for multiple conditions, if_else is for one condition?

Comment: @RandomMonitor No. Both `case_when()` and `if_else()` are for multiple conditions (i.e. a condition vector of length > 1). The difference between the two is that `if_else()` accepts a single condition *expression*, whereas `case_when()` accepts multiple expressions and tests them in turn. But both are vectorised.

Comment: I'm sorry, I still don't see what you mean. Are you saying that if_else() is meant for cases like ````if_else(condition1 & condition2, true, false)```` and not ````if_else(onlycondition, true, false)````? And that in latter situations one should use regular if...else? But regardless of that, you say that the key difference between ifelse and if_else in my problem is that ifelse has this special case where none of the conditions are true or false? But in my problem, there should be no situation where it's not true nor false - either the vector has all NAs or not.

Comment: No. I am saying that `if_else()` (and `ifelse()`!) is meant for cases where `condition` is a *vector* of length > 1. `if_else(c(cond1, cond2, cond3), something, something_else)`; or `if_else(cars$speed > 15, "fast car", "slow car")`.

Comment: Ok, returning to this because I encountered the same problem again, and I think I finally understand what you said. So thanks.
However, is it so that you answer works only for cases where the condition isn't a vector? So I should use if_else (or ifelse) when it is a vector, and if...else if it's not? But my new case is that it might be either (or rather, the vector might be of zero length, because that's what max(x, na.rm = T) gives if x is only NAs) - how should this case be handled?